# import checking for grails-groovy in Netbeans 7.0

Tags: netbeans, groovy

I have a service - reportservice.groovy which has a big list of imports, many of them unused. Is there a quick way in Netbeans IDE 7.0 to remove the unwanted ones. (its not showing any warning/error stripes in the right column). If some plugin does this check I would like to know it.
Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans support for both grails and groovy is about 2 years old.

if you want an ide, you're better off using Eclipse with the latest groovy plugin installed, or [sts from Spring](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts)

or intellij paid edition has great support as well